# How to validate form field with array values[] in laravel?

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to validate form field with array value.

```
    $this->validate($request, [

        'includes' => 'required',
        'excludes' => 'required'
    ]);
```

HTML is as follows:

```
<input type="text" name="excludes[]" id="package_exclude"
                                                   class="form-control">
<input type="text" name="includes[]" id="package_include"
                                                   class="form-control">
```

The outputted value of $request->includes gives ["Include Value One","Include Value Two"] which is working fine..
But the validation doesn't works..

Comment: you need to write custom validation for this

Comment: How about this: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#validating-arrays

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you want the arrays to have at least one value? In this case, you can use the [`min`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#rule-min) validation rule:

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'includes' => 'required|min:1',
    'excludes' => 'required|min:1'
]);
```